# Are there any conventions for Haskell-like type signatures in Javascript

Tags: javascript, types, functional-programming, type-signature

When I eventually stumbled upon [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), the importance of type signatures immediately became clear to me. Instead of looking for ambiguous and imprecise function names, you just search for type signatures:

```
inc :: Number a => a -> a
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
head :: [a] -> a
```

Hoogle makes code reuse a first class affiar :) Since Javascript isn't a purely functional language, one quickly encounters problems. Given is this naive curry implementation:

```
function curry(n, f) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    if (typeof n === 'undefined')
        args[1] = f.length;
    if (n === args.length - 2)
        return f.apply(undefined, args.slice(2));
    return function() {
        return curry.apply(undefined, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
}

function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
var addC = curry(2, add);

addC(2)(3); // 5
addC(2, 3); // 5
```

How could the corresponding type signature look like?

```
Number -> ((a1, ..., aN) -> b) -> (a1 -> ... -> aN -> b)
| Number -> ((a1, ..., aN) -> b) -> ((a1, ..., aN) -> b) // ???
```

This is hideous and not the desired result. In purely functional languages functions always have exactly one parameter - in JavaScript any number.

Are there any conventions how impure language features in Javascript can be expressed with the type signature system of Haskell (I guess it is based on Hindley-Milner)? Is there a (standardized) adaptation to javascript?

Comment: A greater problem is the lack of typing in Javascript in the first place.

Comment: I love the dynamic (proto)typing of javascript, cheers!

Comment: @IvenMarquardt and you are of course aware that the dynamic nature directly contrasts having those signatures?

Comment: I don't think there are any conventions. Type signatures make most sense for pure functions, where they are easy; if you want to express something dynamic like variadic arguments you have to come up with your own syntax. I've seen many, most are understandable, others not so much.

Comment: `Number -> ((a1, …, aN) -> b) -> (a1 -> … -> aN -> b)` feels right. Maybe `(Number, (a1, …, aN) -> b) -> (a1 -> … -> aN -> b)`. You even could use dependent typing to express that the `Number` is the number or parameters `N`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Yes, I am aware of that, but in JavaScript it is all about pragmatism

Comment: @IvenMarquardt it's about pragmatism *for particular usecases*. Haskell is also pragmatic, albeit it targets programs/problems that require a greater degree of reliability, I'd say. For that, the added burden of advanced typechecking is overweighted by the quality of the resulting product.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Compared to Haskell Javascript is immature. It's not really worth arguing about. Thank you for your answer, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any conventions how impure language features in Javascript can be expressed with the type signature system of Haskell?

This is more complex that you'd think. To illustrate:

```
function f(a,b) { return a + b; }
```

At the simplest case, this is `Int -> Int -> Int`. If you wanted to actually cater for `+` working for strings, you'd need something like:

```
Addable a => a -> a -> a
```

But hey! - you would shout - in JS we can add numbers to strings as well! (at this point you need `MultiParamTypeClasses` which is a Haskell extension)

```
Addable a b => a -> b -> a
```

Perfect. Now we only have to implement `Addable String String`, `Addable Int Int` and `Addable String Int`. See how much you need, and we haven't even touched impure functions yet!

When you introduce `this`, you pretty much introduce `State`. And since every function can `throw`, you need `MonadError` as well. And then they all have `IO` (`console.log`) available, right?

For that *pretty much every* function in JS would need to be marked as `RWST IO`, kind of defeating the purpose of monadic signatures.

> I got here two years later and thought I could spell out the actual signature this would produce:
>   Note that `Addable` would probably need to be able to add two distinct types to another, third type to fulfill all current JS behaviour. You'd also need to specify `R`, `W`, and `S`.
>
> `forall a b c m. (MonadError m, MonadIO m, Addable a b c) => a -> b -> RWST R W S m c`

---

You see, Haskell is powerful enough to express side effects as static signatures. Other languages, such as Idris, can also do so, but in a slightly different way. However, it comes at a great expense: every function is now limited to only do what's in its signature.

On the other hand, one of JS' biggest strengths lies in its dynamic nature. The fact that you can write a very complex data operation very easily:

```
function f(a) {
    console.log(a + this.b);
    this.c(function() {
         setTimeout(console.log(a), 100);
    });
}
```

Is *a huge benefit*. Writing a signature for that in Haskell would take ages and would be meaningless if you rewrote it five minutes later.

Sadly, I think that what you're asking for won't happen very soon. To clarify, I strictly mean a type system as powerful as what Haskell has, combined with the elastic and fast prototyping of JS (or Lua, which is similar but better in my opinion). To not sound overly pessimistic, pluggable type systems are being researched and hopefully we'll see more languages utilizing them in the future.

`<opinion>`I can't see any of the javalike JS addons, including horrible ES6 `class`, being even remotely competitive for that, though.`</opinion>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the good insight into Haskell's type system! But this is way too formal. I guess most JS devs don't use type signatures(-like constructions) at all. And those who do, do all their own thing. All I am looking for is a bit more standardization.

Comment: Clarification for non-Haskellers: `RWST IO` is a combined monad transformer composed of reader, writer and state transformer, that is added to an IO monad. Transformer are required in Haskell to combine monads of different types